Increase of self-intersection of the canonical divisor on complex smooth projective surfaces
Could anybody tell me where can I find a formula for the increase of the self-intersection of the canonical divisor when, in a smooth complex projective surface, a configuration of curves with negative-defined self-intersection matrix is collapsed to a normal point? Or could anybody provide me with such a formula?
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Note the question only makes sense if the resulting singular surface is $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein. This will be the case if e.g. the singularities are rational (see this answer) but could fail in general e.g. the cone over a higher genus curve embedded by a line bundle which is not proportional to the canonical.
Suppose then that $X$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein projective surface and $\mu : Y \to X$ is a log resolution of singularities. Denote the exceptional curves by $E_i$ and let $g_i = g(E_i)$, $n_i = -E_i^2$ and $m_{ij} = E_i.E_j$. We can write
$$
\mu^*K_X = K_Y + \sum a_i E_i \quad (\ast)
$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then by the projection formula we have the following.
$$
K_X^2 = K_X.\mu_*K_Y = (\mu^*K_X).K_Y = K_Y^2 + \sum a_i K_Y.E_i \quad (\ast \ast)
$$
We can compute $K_Y.E_i$ using the adjunction formula: $(K_Y + E_i)|_{E_i} = K_{E_i}$ so $K_Y.E_i = 2g_i - 2 + n_i$. Intersecting equation $(\ast)$ with each $E_j$ yields
$$
0 = K_Y.E_j + a_jE_j^2 + \sum_{i \neq j} a_i E_i.E_j = 2g_j - 2 + (1 - a_j)n_j + \sum_{i \neq j} a_im_{ij}. 
$$
Now we can solve this system of linear equations for $a_j$ and use $(\ast \ast)$ to compute
$$
K_X^2 - K_Y^2 = \sum a_i(2g_i - 2 + n_i). 
$$
